# Trying to create instance of another class but creates instance of stdClass in PHP

Tags: php, instantiation, stdclass

I coded for creating instance of `clsDegree` like below:

```
$degree = new clsDegree();
```

but I found `$degree` is object of `stdClass` and contains no attribute from `clsDegree` class.When I tried it on another page, it gives me `clsDegree` object then what may the problem with previous one.

Comment: You have to be more specific and give us more code. `stdClass` is PHP's generic empty class, so something is wrong.

Comment: he probably didn't include the clsDegree class. Oh, and try to stick to standards: class names start with capital letters

Comment: Actually there are many php files involved in this example, I'm giving in detail and simpler as much I can: degree.BO.php call get method from clsDegree(degree.api.class.php), this method call get method from clsDegreeManager(degree.manager.class.php), now in this method I wrote $degree=new clsDegree(); but $degree is resulted in stdClass object. Files containing definition of clsDegree included in file degree.BO.php

Comment: Thank you guys, @Pinoniq Then I should get error class not found!

Comment: Is `$degree` the correct class immediately after you instantiate it? If it is, I would add `var_dump($degree);` throughout your code and isolate the point at which it becomes altered. If it is the wrong class I would check if `class_exists("clsDegree")`, as perhaps your error reporting is isn't at the level you expect. Otherwise, is there something funky going on in the class constructor?

Comment: Thank you! @faintsignal problem solved, degree class contains private attribute so var_dump($degree) displays object as instance of stdClass. Because of same reason although I have initialized those variables I can not see them with var_dump.

Comment: `var_dump()` should not obfuscate attributes based on their declared visibility unless you are using PHP 4.